# Problem with the Radeon propietary driver

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

Yesterday I switched from Debian 7.6 (Wheezy) to Ubuntu 13.10. In Debian following the [official tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/es/ATIProprietary) I could install the ATI propietary drivers from repositories. But in  Ubuntu following the [official tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) I couldn't install it. My GPU is a ATI HD4330 or RV710/M92 (yes, it's compatible)

The first way to install it, was from repositories, but when I had to run aticonfig --initial the return was "aticonfig is not installed". The same happend with amdconfig. The second way to do it from repositories didn't work either, when I tried to run aticonfig --initial, the return was "your device is not compatibe", or something like that.

So I tried to install the ATI Cathalist, but after installing it, I reboot my compueter, but it wasn't working properly, the resolution was 640x480 instead of 1366x768 and when I tried to login the system crashed and it retuned back to the login screen. In TTY1 startx doesn't work either.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with the AMD/ATI driver too (Radeon 5870), I suggest you to download the drivers from the AMD site.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Installing_upstream_drivers_directly_from_AMD.27s_website

The last drivers doesn't give support to the HD4000 series:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst14-4LINReleaseNotes.aspx
Here you'll find drivers for your video card:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64

But first, may be you'll need to uninstall the proprietary driver and install the open source version to get your desktop again.

```
sudo /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```